# What are my options for a fire rated door for a 32" x 36" rough opening?

Tags: doors, crawlspace, fireproof

The original floor plan of our split level home had the crawl space door in the garage. The previous owners converted half of the garage to a laundry room and put up wainscoting and a matching wood door in front of the crawl space. None of the improvements were done to code or with a permit.

The inspection states that we need to have a fire rated door to the crawl space. Can someone explain exactly what this means?

I found a fire rated utility access door at HD, but the biggest size is 22" by 30" and the actual door opening is closer to 32" by 36".

1. Should it be framed in?
2. Drywalled over?
3. How do I get it to match the current wainscoting?

Further, why do I need a fire rated door when it's inside the house and the walls were not fire rated?

This is it: [image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add 5/8" (16 mm) sheetrock to the back of the door.  That would make it a fire rated surface.  If that matched up with the sheetrock at the right, it would be almost a continuous surface.  If I had to live with it, that is what I would do.

If it is to sell the house, the new owners either won't be used to the access or won't know about it.  Sheetrocking it in would be cheap and easy.

Comment: Part of the fire rating process is to seal all the gaps between two spaces with fire rated caulk/foam or other rated materials. If the door is still operable, you'll have gaps that don't meet the fire code.

Comment: You can buy fire rated door seals just google it and you will find them. I doubt your local hardware store would carry it.

Comment: @wallyk - Thank you for the response! That's almost exactly what the employee at HD told my husband. So he conveyed that to our realtor who in turn conveyed it to the borrower. They said it was unacceptable. The borrowers were actually there with the inspector when he did the inspection and they want a receipt from a contractor but that is not written into the contract.

Comment: @BMitch & Justin Kuhs - so the door just needs some caulk/foam or a door seal? It needs to be accessible, it's the only way to turn on or off the water to the house. So putting that in, you could still open and close the door?

Comment: Given you and your husband's background, if you want to close the sale with them, it sounds like this is one of the times where it is more than worth it to just hire it out.

Comment: @NikkiPeterson I was just pointing out that you can't simply add fire rated drywall or some other material to an existing access panel to make it fire rated, you need the seals around the door. Get something that's prebuilt for the requirement.

Comment: @Mike - If we absolutely have to, we will hire someone. But we've sunk just about every cent we have into the house and we'll be lucky to break even. So we wanted to explore other options first.

Comment: @BMitch - Ok, so if we were to get the 22"X30" prebuilt door, how we would install it since the opening is so much bigger? And will it matter that the walls are not fire rated? The installation instructions for the door state that it must be installed in a fire rated wall. Our biggest concern with hiring a contractor is that he will come in and say yes we can do a fire rated door, but the walls need to be fire rated too which is basically tearing everything down and starting over. We close in 3 weeks and not a lot of $ to work with.

Comment: @NikkiPeterson You'll need to frame the opening to the appropriate size, and extend the wall material to the sides of the new door. The drywall may be fire rated (5/8" type X), and if so you only need to extend that rather than replace the entire wall.

Comment: @NikkiPeterson:  Given all the additional constraints, what is the possibility of adding a new water shutoff valve somewhere else more accessible and closing this wall up?

Comment: @BMitch - Ok, that makes sense. I will have my husband see if the existing drywall is fire rated.

Comment: @wallyk - I think that would require more work than it's worth. We wouldn't even know where to start. We close on the house in three weeks so I need a solution that is not only as inexpensive as possible, but fast.

Comment: @NikkiPeterson:  What I propose is maybe one day's work.  $250 for a plumber, $300 for a sheetrock dude, and maybe $100 worth of disposal.